# How to force rendering while a pop-up menu is active in GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I've noticed that if the a pop-up menu is active, the rendering process is frozen until I click on the menu. I've searched the problem and came up with this function

`void glutMenuStatusFunc(void (*func)(int status, int x, int y);`

With these flags `GLUT_MENU_IN_USE or GLUT_MENU_NOT_IN_USE`, I can tell if the menu is active. What I'm trying to do is to force rendering while the menu is active. This is what I've done

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    ...
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutIdleFunc(glutIdle);
    glutMenuStatusFunc(MenuStatus);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

and the `MenuStatus` is

```
void MenuStatus(int status,int x, int y)
{
    if ( status == GLUT_MENU_IN_USE )
        glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

With this solution `glutPostRedisplay()` is triggered once. If I run `while()`, the application will freeze. Any suggestions how to force rendering continuously while the a pop-up menu is active?

Comment: GLUT is largely obsolete. Use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) instead.

Comment: @hidefromkgb, I'm aware of that. Also, GLFW doesn't support popup menus.